# CURAND device API: Segmentation fault в ядре. В чем ошибка?

Tags: c++, случайные-числа, cuda

Вот пример Curand device API. Я дописал в ядро generate строчку randomArray[ind] = RANDOM; и соответственно в main добавил выделение памяти и копирование данных. Однако с этой строчкой ядро стало падать по Segmentation fault. В чем я ошибся?

```
#include <cuda.h>
#include <curand_kernel.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define CUDA_CALL(x) do { if((x) != cudaSuccess) { \
printf("Error at %s:%d -- %s\n",__FILE__,__LINE__, cudaGetErrorString(x)); \
return EXIT_FAILURE;}} while(0)

#define N 1

__global__ void setup_kernel ( curandState * state, unsigned long seed )
{
    int id = threadIdx.x;
    curand_init ( seed, id, 0, &state[id] );
}

__global__ void generate( curandState* globalState, float * randomArray ) 
{
    int ind = threadIdx.x;
    curandState localState = globalState[ind];
    float RANDOM = curand_uniform( &localState );
    randomArray[ind] = RANDOM;
    globalState[ind] = localState;
}

int main( int argc, char** argv) 
{
    dim3 tpb(N,1,1);
    curandState* devStates;
    float * randomValues = new float[N];
    float * devRandomValues;

    CUDA_CALL(cudaMalloc ( &devStates, N*sizeof( curandState ) ));
    CUDA_CALL(cudaMalloc ( &devRandomValues, N*sizeof( *randomValues ) ));

    // setup seeds
    setup_kernel <<< 1, tpb >>> ( devStates, time(NULL) );

    printf("%s\n", cudaGetErrorString(cudaGetLastError()));

    // generate random numbers
    generate <<< 1, tpb >>> ( devStates, randomValues );

    printf("%s\n", cudaGetErrorString(cudaGetLastError()));

    CUDA_CALL(cudaMemcpy      ( randomValues, devRandomValues, N*sizeof(*randomValues), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost ));

    for(int i=0;i<N;i++)
    {
        printf("%f\n", randomValues[i]);
    }

    CUDA_CALL(cudaFree(devRandomValues));
    CUDA_CALL(cudaFree(devStates));

    delete randomValues;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Не нравится мне строка

```
generate <<< 1, tpb >>> ( devStates, randomValues );
```

По-моему, нужно писать

```
generate <<< 1, tpb >>> ( devStates, devRandomValues );
```

Мы же передаем кернелю адрес массива в памяти девайса

Comment: Тьфу ты, вот я идиот. Да, так заработало. Спасибо.